# How to intercept enter key on a link in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to intercept enter key on a link without using Bookmarklet (`href="javascript:..."`)?

I was trying this:

```js
addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  if (e.charCode == 13) {
    alert('x');
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#">this is link</a>
```

If you press the tab and enter the code is not triggered. Only when the link is not in focus the alert will be triggered. Is there a way to trigger JavaScript on press enter over a link? Or is `href` the only way? There should be a way to use JavaScript and not have to put JavaScript into every link on the page.

And if you ask why I need this, it's because of this question: [how to open a file upload dialog box when a hyperlink is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37386514/387194), I want to update my answer and see if I can trigger click on `input[type="file"]` when you press enter.

Comment: maybe a `return false` or check what `e.target` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the handler to trigger only when the link is focused, add the listener to element itself.

To have a more consistent keyboard event handling, listen for `keydown` instead of `keypress` [which has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event).

To intercept enter's default action of opening the link, use `event.preventDefault()`

Lastly, avoid charcodes or keycodes, use `key` instead which is more consistent across different keyboard layouts.

```js
link.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  const { key } = e
  console.log(key);
  if (key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('You just tried opening Google');
  }
});
```

```html
<a id="link" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know that keypress was deprecated.

Comment: @jcubic You can use a delegated event as well, only that the link needs `tabindex` being set. When delegating, target check is more likely needed, depending on the other content of the page.